# Rails: Can't render a page that is routed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I routed a page called "classrooms#new". But it won't show up when I click the button that is routed to it. 
Here are my routes for the classroom:
(Routes.rb)

```
get 'classrooms/index'
get 'classrooms/new'
```

Here is the button it's linked to: 
(Nav_link_for_auth.html.erb)

```
<li><%= link_to 'Create a Class', 'classrooms#new' %></li>
```

The code in for this is in app/views/classrooms/new.html.erb

```
<section class="newclass_form">
    <%= render 'layouts/newclass_form' %>
</section>
```

Form URL:

```
<%= form_for :classroom, html: { multipart: true }, url: classrooms_new_path do |f| %>
<h2>Create a Class!</h2>
#additional code here
```

Here is what happens when I click to see it: 
[image]

There is a route for it, so why won't it show up?
Thanks so much!

Comment: I believe you may want: `<li><%= link_to 'Create a Class', 'classrooms/new' %></li>`.

Comment: you want a slash in that code, not the #.  The # is used to specify an action inside the controller in the routes file, but notice that it is putting that inside the route.  You want classrooms/new, not classrooms#new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want:

```
  <li><%= link_to 'Create a Class', 'classrooms/new' %></li>
```

If you look at the url in your browser screen shot, you'll see that

```
  <li><%= link_to 'Create a Class', 'classrooms#new' %></li>
```

yields:

```
  https://kidznotes-app-cynthiarios.c9users.io/classrooms#new
```

but you want:

```
  https://kidznotes-app-cynthiarios.c9users.io/classrooms/new
```

Also, I would suggest changing:

```
  get 'classrooms/index'
  get 'classrooms/new'
```

to:

```
  resources :classrooms
```

Then I would do:

```
  <li><%= link_to 'Create a Class', new_classroom_path %></li>
```

To link to `Classrooms#index`, you would do something like:

```
  link_to 'Classrooms', classrooms_path
```

Also, I think this is wrong:

```
<%= form_for :classroom, html: { multipart: true }, url: classrooms_new_path do |f| %>
  <h2>Create a Class!</h2>
  #additional code here
```

It will try to submit to `classrooms_new_path`, and you don't have that defined as a route. Instead, try something like:

```
<%= form_for :classroom, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
  <h2>Create a Class!</h2>
  #additional code here
```